# React Router: Active Link not matching the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am following the example of react-redux: Adding React Router to the Project

```
components/Root.js


import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ App }/>
                <Route path="/:filter" component={ App }/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

export default Root;
```

components/Footer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import FilterLink from '../containers/FilterLink'

const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {" "}
    <FilterLink filter="all">
      All
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="active">
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="completed">
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
)

export default Footer
```

containers/FilterLink.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => {

    console.log("filter: "+filter);
    console.log("children: "+children);

    return (
      <NavLink
        to={filter === 'all' ? '' : filter}
        activeStyle={{
          textDecoration: 'none',
          color: 'black',
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </NavLink>
    );

}

export default FilterLink;
```

The results i get are:

[image: screenshot_20171109_195739]

[image: screenshot_20171109_195723]

As per the code the active link should be same as the URL. Even the URL shows "localhost:3008/active" the active link shows as "all"  and similar to completed.

Whats going wrong and why the corresponding link is not getting activated as per the URL.

Comment: Does this also happen when you load the page at "localhost:3008/active"?
Or is it only wrong when clicking the NavLinks?

Comment: it happens even when loading page directly `localhost:3008/active` on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `/`

```
const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => {

  console.log("filter: "+filter);
  console.log("children: "+children);

  return (
    <NavLink
      // / is added via string interpolation
      to={filter === 'all' ? '' : `/${filter}`}
      activeStyle={{
        textDecoration: 'none',
        color: 'black',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NavLink>
  );

}
```

or

```
import React from 'react'
import FilterLink from '../containers/FilterLink'

const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {" "}
    <FilterLink filter="/all">
      All
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="/active">
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="/completed">
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
)

export default Footer
```

and update the check in the FilterLink Component:

```
to={filter === '/all' ? '' : filter}
```

Comment: That almost worked. But for both `active` and `complete` the `all` link in the footer is showing as activated. For `private` both `private` and `all` shown as activated. For `completed` both `completed` and `all` are shown as activated links. `all` link is showing activated always. why

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5118 was the issue with "/" always active